# How to create a dictionary property using struct in C#?

Tags: c#, properties, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains a struct as key, I have to create a property for the dictionary

```
private Dictionary<string, Data> m_dictParam;

   struct Data
    {
        public string MinValue { get; set; }
        public string MaxValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to create property of dictionary using that struct

When I try to do like this

```
    public Dictionary<string,Data> MinMax
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

This error happens:

> *Inconsistent accessibility property type system.Collections.Generic.Dictionary*

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the struct as public. Your property is public but the struct isn't so any component who can access only public things won't be able to use your property since it can't recognize the key type.

```
public struct Data
    {
        public string MinValue { get; set; }
        public string MaxValue { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Data` struct is non-`public`, and you are trying to expose it publicly.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the struct is internal, try declaring it as

```
public struct Data {
    // etc
}
```